# Lazy formatted recursive JSON type can't be found as implicit value

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json, spray-routing

I'm using Spray to build a REST API. 
One of my JSON datatypes are recursive:

```
case class Container(id: String,
                 name: String,
                 read_only: Boolean,
                 containers: List[Container],
                 content: List[Content])

object PeriusJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val contentFormat = jsonFormat8(Content)
  implicit val containerFormat: JsonFormat[Container] = lazyFormat(jsonFormat5(Container))
}
```

When completing the route in the HttpService I get the following error:

```
Error:(49, 18) could not find implicit value for parameter um: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[Container]
        entity(as[Container]) { container =>
                 ^

Error:(49, 18) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit um: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[Container])spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[Container].
Unspecified value parameter um.
        entity(as[Container]) { container =>
                 ^
```

The HttpService looks like this:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

import PeriusJsonProtocol._

class RestServiceActor extends Actor with RestService {
  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(projectsRoute)
}

// this trait defines our service behavior independently from the service actor
trait RestService extends HttpService {
  private val PROJECTS  = "projects"

  val projectsRoute =
    path(PROJECTS) {
      get {
        complete(MongoUtil.getAll(PROJECTS, META) map ContainerMap.fromBson)
        //complete(Container("test", "name", false, List(), List()))
      } ~ post {
        entity(as[Container]) { 
          //complete(MongoUtil.insertProject(container))
          complete(container)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The `complete` in the `GET` works, even though that function returns a list of Containers. The commented out line in the `get` does not work however and it does not work to implicitly convert the Container in `post`, as can be seen in the error messages. What should I do to make the container work implicitly and still keep its recursive structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Container class is a root level json so you need to change the respective implicit to:

```
implicit val containerFormat: RootJsonFormat[Container] = rootFormat(lazyFormat(jsonFormat5(Container)))
```

Comment: So simple and yet so many hours wasted on my part, thank you so much!